# Studies on the effects of using online platforms in teaching mathematics on students' beliefs about mathematics

Tags: undergraduate-education, education-research, online-instruction, onlineplatforms

Are you aware of any research examining the impact of utilizing online platforms in teaching mathematics, on students' beliefs about mathematics? To give you an example of the kind of beliefs that I have in mind, does the use of online platforms promote the belief that the goal of solving problems in mathematics is to find the correct answer? Surprisingly, my search for such studies did not find any notable results.

Comment: Sounds like a good master- or PhD-project, or an article to write.

Comment: The answer to this question would take the form of a literature review. Have you consulted a librarian? What journals have you searched for and in?

Comment: We can simultaneously search several databases with proper keywords. I did not search individual journals.

Comment: Do you have some particular online platform presentations in mind? An online platform in general is just a delivery method and I would naively presume that people's beliefs about mathematics are normally formed by the content and the form of the message rather than by the medium itself. But, perhaps, I'm a bit behind the latest educational ideas :-)

Comment: @fedja That is a good question. I did not have any particular platform in mind. My question is more about the form of homework and assessments that are used with online platforms. It is often (but not always) the case that homework and assessment questions that are used with online platforms require students to either submit or select the final answer. So, I was wondering whether this practice may promote the belief among students that the goal of solving problems in mathematics is to find the correct or the final answer.